# AWS SNS How can I send JSON message to SNS via Javascript

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

When I try to use with below

```
Message: Data.json,
```

it returns error said the message is only be string.

Does anyone has suggestion on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a Python object (`Data`) to a JSON-formatted string with:

```
Message: json.dumps(Data)
```

The program will also need to use: `import json`